# apt reinstall local package if package was previously installed by repository

Tags: linux, debian, git, ruby

before I embark into this I would like to ask for clarification.

I have a github package installed in Debian via its own repository. Now the project has been archived and its repo no longer works.

I have a lot of ruby gems which I don't think are all needed but this package make use of some of those gems.. I would like to purge all the installed gems and reinstall the package via:

```
apt install --reinstall ./local_downloaded_release_package.deb
```

Instead of using the repository.

Will that work? Or should I "apt remove the package" before I can install the same package from a local source?

Thanks

Comment: hmm, I think package *names* and version numbers might play a part here. If the package name is the same, and the version neatly incremented, it would be a simple reinstall. Also consider your package *configuration* which a purse would remove

Comment: Package name and version should be the same and I won't issue a "remove --purge" command, just "remove".